# UILongPressGestureRecognizer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am trying to create an app where UIButtons can be draged and dropped when a UILongPressGestureRecognizer gesture is fired.

I have:

```
UIGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]
initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
```

And

```
- (void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:self.view];

    switch (recognizer.state) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
            //NSLog(@"handleLongPress: StateBegan");
            break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:
            if(location.y > 75.0 && location.x > 25 && location.x < 300)
                button.frame = CGRectMake(location.x-25, location.y-15, 50, 30);           
            break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
            //NSLog(@"handleLongPress: StateEnded");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }   
}
```

This works great with one button (namely the ivar `button`). How can I send to the handleLongPress function the current button that is being pressed? In other words, I would like to do something like the following where I pass in `sender`

```
- (void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)recognizer:(id)sender {
    CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:self.view];

    switch (recognizer.state) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
            //NSLog(@"handleLongPress: StateBegan");
            break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:
            if(location.y > 75.0 && location.x > 25 && location.x < 300)
                sender.frame = CGRectMake(location.x-25, location.y-15, 50, 30);           
            break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
            //NSLog(@"handleLongPress: StateEnded");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Did you try `recognizer.view`?

Answer (score -2):

You'll have to loop through all your button into handleLongPress.
Using locationInView and pointInside:withEvent: to determine which button is under the pressing finger.